# Execute .exe on openmediavault NAS

Tags: permissions, executable, nas

I install a NAS with the [OpenMediaVault distribution](http://www.openmediavault.org/), it works fine but I dont find how to lauch an .exe file stocked on my raid disks in my folders.
When I doubleclic on it, windows tells me I have probably a permission error. I think too but I dont know how what is the options to modify in the openmediavault web interface.

Thank you